# Magento 2 Tax Calculation based on Row Total

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

I have my tax set to calculate tax on **total** however am getting slight miss matches in edge cases with Sage Accounts 50. From what i can tell this calculates on **row total**. So have changed this and flushed my cache however the issue still occurs.

This is how i believe each method to work and how i think Sage is working:

**Row Calculation**

```
Units   Item            Row Ex Vat     Row Total
4       Example Item    57.56          69.072 (69.07)
4       Example Item    57.56          69.072 (69.07)
4       Example Item    57.56          69.072 (69.07)
Total Ex Vat   172.68
Total Inc Vat  207.21
```

So for each row you calculate the Vat on the row total. So `(14.39 x 4) x 1.2 = 69.072` and then round to nearest pound giving `69.07` for each row. This gives the same total of `207.21` that **Sage 50 Accounts** gives and what i want Magento 2 to calculate like.

**Unit Calculation**

```
Units   Item            Ex Vat     Inc Vat         Row Total
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268 (17.27)  69.08
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268 (17.27)  69.08
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268 (17.27)  69.08
Total Ex Vat   172.68
Total Inc Vat  207.24
```

This is how i feel unit calculation works where the tax calculation is based on units. So `14.39 x 1.2 = 17.268` and then rounded to nearest penny giving `17.27` for each unit total. This then gives a total of `207.24` for all units.

**Total Calculation**

```
Units   Item            Ex Vat     Inc Vat         Row Total
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268          69.072
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268          69.072
4       Example Item    14.39      17.268          69.072
Total Ex Vat   172.68
Total Inc Vat  207.216 (207.22)
```

For total calculation i feel there should be no rounding until all the totals are calculated. This works like so i believe. `(14.39 x 12) x 1.2` giving `207.216` which then rounds to nearest penny so `207.22`. I feel like Magento 2 always works like this for me however, no matter how i set in admin.

**Actual Question**

Can anyone suggest what i may have got wrong anywhere or how can i set Magento to work on row totals as i have described. I have set within `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Tax Calculation Method Based On > Row Total` and flushed the configuration tax however my total in this example always shows as 207.22?

**Update**

Flushing all my caches seems to have fixed my issue here. I was previously just flushing configuration so may be one of the others needed flushing too.

Comment: hello @harri, got solution? similar issue i am facing, here is the complete question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart